# DLL Injection, threads and memory releasing

Tags: memory-management, clr, dll-injection

I have a following situation - i inject a dll written in C into another process, that dll loads CLR and starts a thread calling a method from managed class library.

My question is - how and when should I release memory of all these objects, so that target process (in which I inject dll initially) can successfully exit and free it's resources, including releasing a lock from my dll which was injected?

Comment: You mean release memory of the injected DLL? Can you give more info please, it's rather vague and hard to answer in this way.

Comment: Yes. In case if I just inject a DLL and then exit injector process, then target process will remain in memory and retain file lock of the injected dll, even if user has closed GUI part of the target process.

Comment: This cannot be answered without you carefully documenting how you inject the DLL in the first place.  Injecting the CLR is pretty nasty btw.

Comment: I was using CreateRemoteThread.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

since you are already DLL injecting your code its only small step further to hook the exit / cleanup call of your target process and do:

- Jump to your code
- stop threads
- cleanup mem
- jump back